# The minimum even value in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So, I have this program that asks for the minimum even value in the array and I have written the code but I seem to missed a loop. I will write the correct code but I hope someone would explain why is there a while loop

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">

    var number=new Array(10)

  for(var i=0; i<number.length; i=i+1)
{ 
   number[i] =window.prompt('enter number ','')
   number[i] =parseFloat(number[i])
}

  var y = 0 
  while (number[y] % 2 != 0) //get the first even number in the array
{
    y = y + 1
}
//after you exit the while loop y will have the index of the first even number 

var Min 
Min = number[y] 

 for(var i=0; i<number.length; i=i+1)
{
    if (number[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
            if(number[i]<Min)
            {
                    Min= number[i]
            }
    }
}

document.write(Min)

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

So, this part

```
  var y = 0 
  while (number[y] % 2 != 0) //get the first even number in the array
{
    y = y + 1
}
//after you exit the while loop y will have the index of the first even number
```

I'm finding it hard to really grasp this loop and if I might ask: is there another way to find the minimum value in an array?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The while loop sets the first value of `Min` so that subsequent comparisons work. Here's a far 
simpler and faster way to do the same thing:

```
var min = Infinity; // Start with the biggest number possible
for (var i=myArray.length;i--;){
  var val = myArray[i];
  if (val<min && val%2==0) min = val;
}
```

*This is faster because—unlike the original code—this doesn't iterate over the first non-even values twice. It would be roughly equivalent in speed if the `for` loop in the original started at index `y`, i.e. `for (var i=y+1;i<number.length;++i)`*

*It's also very slightly faster because the `for` loop caches the length of the array instead of looking it up each time, and because it only looks up the value in the array once each loop, not three times. Modern JavaScript runtimes like V8 can optimize naive code to behave similarly, however, so this is not a very important point.*

---

**Edit**: For fun, here's a modern, functional programming approach:

```
var min = Math.min.apply(Math,myArray.filter(function(n){ return n%2==0 }));
```

The above uses [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array of just the even-valued items, and then uses [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass the array of values as parameters to [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min).

Comment: @aablah Since you asked about "another way to find the minimum" I've edited my answer to add an alternative to looping over all the values. If you feel that this has solved your question, you should [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/153741).

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested how to do that in modern Javascript, it goes like this:

```
minEvenElement = Math.min.apply(Math, myArray.filter(function(e) { return !(e % 2) }))
```